# How do you select the highest of a count()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've wrote a query which shows the reasons and the amount of the selected reasons people cancel their orders per state per year:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT LEFT(k.wijk,2) AS state,
         YEAR(a.eind_dt) AS year, 
         opzegreden AS reason, 
         count(*) AS amount
FROM     klant AS k 
JOIN     abon AS a 
ON       k.klant_id = a.lezer
WHERE    opzegreden IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY LEFT(k.wijk,2), year(a.eind_dt), opzegreden
ORDER BY state, year, reason;
```

Which gives this result atm:
[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRbD.png)

Now the only thing I can't seem to make happen is to show the reason which is picked the most per state per year. Which would be reason nr 14 with my current result.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: you should throw ,some sample data.if I use partition function in my query then Why I have to use Group By,Order By etc.Also "storing value like "k.wijk AS state" is bad idea.you should straight away store id in table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair up `top with ties` with window function `row_number` to get the rows with max amount per state per year.

```
select top 1 with ties LEFT(k.wijk, 2) as state,
    YEAR(a.eind_dt) as year,
    opzegreden as reason,
    count(*) as amount
from klant as k
join abon as a on k.klant_id = a.lezer
where opzegreden is not null
group by LEFT(k.wijk, 2),
    year(a.eind_dt),
    opzegreden
order by row_number() over (
        partition by state, year order by amount desc
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:-

```
    SELECT
      state,
      year,
      reason,
      max(amount)
    FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(k.wijk,2) AS state,
    YEAR(a.eind_dt) AS year, 
    opzegreden AS reason, count(*) AS amount
    FROM klant AS k 
    JOIN abon AS a 
    ON k.klant_id = a.lezer
    WHERE opzegreden IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY LEFT(k.wijk,2), year(a.eind_dt), opzegreden
    ORDER BY state, year, reason
    ) d
GROUP BY
  state,
  year,
  reason;
```